# Bloquear para não mostrar outra div enquanto uma já estiver visível para o usuário

Tags: jquery

E ae pessoal, bllz?
Pessoal, estou com uma dúvida, tenho um sistema de postagem similar ao do facebook, e como sabem, existe no post para o usuário abrir as configurações para excluir e etc, que ao clicar ele exibe a div com as opções, certo, até aí tudo bem, fiz o sistema para poder aplicar a class 'block' nessa div ao clicar no icone das opções... O problema é, quando o usuário clica no icone, ele exibe, mas ele só desaparece se apertar novamente no icone, e queria que ele sumisse ao clicar em qualquer outro lugar, e tipo, eu apertei exibiu uma, se eu deixar aberta e apertar na configuração de outra publicação, fica visível as duas, e eu queria que sumisse quando eu apertasse em qualquer outro lugar e quando apertasse em uma se tivesse já alguma visível, ele escondesse a visível e mostrasse a que o usuário solicitou, tentei fazer isso com Blur(), mas por algum motivo não deu certo, segue abaixo o código .js, lembrando que estou usando JQuery:::

```
//Código Js, função para exibir a div .configsOp e também esconder...
$('.configsPost .icon').on('click', function(){
   $(this).parent().find('.configsOp').fadeToggle(200).toggleClass('block');
});

//Código que tentei usar para remover a Class Block da div.configsOp
$('.configsOp').blur(function(){
   $(this).fadeToggle(200).removeClass('block');
 });
```

Quem souber me ajuda por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando clicar no ícone, basta esconder todos os outros que estiverem sendo exibidos antes de mostrar, caso ele não possua a classe `block`:

```
//Código Js, função para exibir a div .configsOp e também esconder...
$('.configsPost .icon').on('click', function() {
  // se o div deste ícone não estiver com classe block, remove essa classe de outros divs que podem estar ativos
  if(!$(this).parent().find('.configsOp').hasClass('block')) {
    $('.configsOp').fadeToggle(200).removeClass('block');
  }
  $(this).parent().find('.configsOp').fadeToggle(200).toggleClass('block');
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, Tentei da mesma forma, só que eu não sabia como usar direito o hasClass(), então acabei me atrapalhando, por que eu tinha colocado assim:
if(!$(this).parent().find('.configsOp').hasClass('') == 'block') {
    $('.configsOp').fadeToggle(200).removeClass('block');
  }

Aí Não tinha dado certoo, então eu tentei da forma que tava embaixo
if(!$(this).parent().find('.configsOp').hasClass('block') == 'block') {
    $('.configsOp').fadeToggle(200).removeClass('block');
  }
Por que eu não sabia como fazia essas verificações de classes com JQuery, apenas com JavaScript puro

Comment: E a sua forma ficou muitoo boa, eu apenas removi o fadeToogle(), por que estava dando um pequeno probleminha no efeito de visibilidade, tipo, ele mostrava e dps dava tipo uma piscada sabe pra mostrar com o efeito, então eu resolvi tirar mesmo e ficou bem melhor, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Beleza. Se estiver com outras dúvidas com as funções do JQuery, a documentação deles é ótima, https://api.jquery.com/ - tem a descrição de cada função e alguns exemplos

Answer (score 0):

Você ira precisar verificar se existe qualquer evento de clique fora de sua div depois de ela ser clicada, para isso você precisa adicionar um listener de eventos no seu código e limitar o evento para somente ser executado em elementos diferente do seu botão (no exemplo abaixo limitei ao botão e aos links)

```js
function ocultar(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).parents('.configsPost.icon').length) {
    $('.configsOp').removeClass("block");
  }
}
document.addEventListener("click", ocultar);
$('.configsPost.icon').on('click', function mostrar() {

  $('.configsOp').addClass("block");

});
```

```css
.configsOp {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

.block {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='configsPost icon'>
  <button>Clique para opções</button>
  <div class='configsOp'>
    <a href='#'>opcão 1</a>
    <a href='#'>opção 2</a>
    <div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Essa não funcionou pra mim não.

Comment: E não quero chamar função no código HTML não, mas sim chamar a div diretamente no código.

Comment: execute o snippet que enviei no próprio stack overflow (botão executar) e verifique se possuí o comportamento desejado, com relação a não chamar no código html posso modificar meu exemplo sem problemas

Comment: modifiquei o exemplo para o evento ser executado via javascript ( e não inserido diretamente no código html)

Answer (score 0):

Pessoaal, obrigado pela força novamente, me ajudaram demais mesmo nisso.
E o código final ficou assim pelo do @Dudaskank:

```
//Código Js, função para exibir a div .configsOp e também esconder...
$('.configsPost .icon').on('click', function() {
  // se o div deste ícone não estiver com classe block, remove essa classe de outros divs que podem estar ativos
  if(!$(this).parent().find('.configsOp').hasClass('block')) {
    $('.configsOp').removeClass('block');
  }
  $(this).parent().find('.configsOp').toggleClass('block');
});
```

Deixei com os comentários dele aqui no site para vocês, eu retirei apenas os fadeToggle(), pois estavam dando um pequenino problema na hora da exibição, pois ele mostrava instantâneamente a div e depois adicionava o efeito, então dava uma piscada na hora que mostrava. Mas tá aí, sem nenhum erro para quem estiver com caso igual ou semelhante